# Obtener indice de combobox en java y registrarlo como booleano en mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas noches estoy obteniendo el indice de un combobox para manejar el sexo masculino o femenino y quiero registrarlo en la base de datos como booleano, tengo esto al momento pero me genera error.

```
               int bb=combobox.getSelectedIndex();
               if(bb==0){
                try {
                sql="INSERT INTO personas(sexo) values (?)";

                PreparedStatement ps = miConexion.prepareStatement(sql);

                ps.setInt(bb,bb);
                int n=ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(addUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

      }
```

Comment: Pero, ¿qué error estás teniendo?

Comment: GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'sexo' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que estas usando ? para el procedimiento preparado, entonces en ps.setInt(0, bb); Tenias que indicar el valor inicial, sea 0 o 1 no importa, indícalo individualmente con 0.

```
        PreparedStatement ps = miConexion.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setInt(0,bb);
            int n=ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(addUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes, es que no estás pasando correctamente el parámetro a la consulta. El método `PreparedStatement.setInt(...)` espera en la primera posición el índice del parámetros que deseas rellenar, pero este índice comienza en 1, no en 0. Por lo que si condicionas a que la variable `bb` sea 0 para ejecutar la consulta, y luego utilizas el valor de dicha variable (que es 0), para setear los datos de los parámetros (`ps.setInt(bb, bb)`), estás cometiendo un error, ya que en la posición 0 no hay parámetros que rellenar.

Por lo tanto, te recomiendo que no utilices `bb` como valor del índice de los parámetros de la consulta. En vez de eso utiliza un valor fijo, por ejemplo: `ps.setInt(1, bb)`.